# CSS Animation not triggered in IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge

My CSS animation is not triggered properly: the opacity is animated but not the translate.

Look: https://jsfiddle.net/bLxb8k3s/

Apparently, it's because IE and Edge can't animate between a `translateY` and a `translate`.

I've made a test where I replaced my `translate(0, 0)` by `translateY(0)`: https://jsfiddle.net/gy129xyw/1/

And it works.

But I want to keep my keyframes as they are (with a `translate(0,0)`) because I use it a lot in others pages, with different animations.

Do you think I've missed something, or is it indeed a bug of IE and Edge?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's a bug. I don't have 100% confirmation but even with `-ms` or `-webkit` it doesn't work.

Comment: So why not change `transform: translateY(100%);` to `transform: translate(0, 100%);` ... I mean either way, you can't animate the same property with 2 different keyframes anyway

Comment: And here is a sample working just fine in IE/Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/bLxb8k3s/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem using percentage in translate(%, %). I tried to to change it to fixed px and it works. also don't forget about the prefixes

https://jsfiddle.net/bLxb8k3s/1/

```
span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 200px );
    -ms-transform: translateY( 200px );
    animation: slideIn .7s .7s both;
}
```